# What is the code that allows the user to display data in a DataGrid depending on what is typed?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, ado.net

I created this form :

[image]

and this is the code source of this form :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace GESTION_DE_STAGE
{
    public partial class RechercheEtablissement : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
    {
        private BindingManagerBase db;
        SQL sql = new SQL();
        public RechercheEtablissement()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void RechercheEtablissement_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sql.cn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter daEtablissement = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Etablissement", sql.cn);
            daEtablissement.Fill(sql.ds, "Etablissement");
            db = this.BindingContext[sql.ds.Tables["Etablissement"]];
            id.DataBindings.Add("text", sql.ds.Tables["Etablissement"], "Id_Etablissement");
            nom.DataBindings.Add("text", sql.ds.Tables["Etablissement"], "Nom_Etablissement");
            ville.DataBindings.Add("text", sql.ds.Tables["Etablissement"], "Ville_Etablissement");
            dgv.DataSource = sql.ds.Tables["Etablissement"];
            for(int i=0; i<sql.ds.Tables["Etablissement"].Rows.Count; i++)
                idE.Properties.Items.Add(sql.ds.Tables["Etablissement"].Rows[i][0]);
        }

        private void first_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            db.Position = 0;
        }

        private void last_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            db.Position = sql.ds.Tables["Etablissement"].Rows.Count - 1;
        }

        private void previous_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            db.Position --;
        }

        private void next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            db.Position ++;
        }

        private void idE_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //The code to update the DataGridView where ID = the selected Item
        }

        private void nomE_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //The code to update the DataGridView where Nom = the String that the user is typing
        }

        private void villeE_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //The code to update the DataGridView where Ville = the String that the user is typing
        }
    }
}
```

My Question is that I want to add a code that display Data in the DataGrid depending on the selected item ine the comboBox or the text in the Nom text field or the Ville text field.

Answer (score 0):

// Associate the event-handling method with theSelectedIndexChanged event.

```
this.ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += 
new System.EventHandler(ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);


private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
        System.EventArgs e)
{
     show data in the dataGrid
}
```

Comment: if you read the code i posted you can see that i wrote the event-handling method but i don't know what is the code that allows me to search

Comment: are you asking how to fill data into the datagrid as when combo box is selected with an item or when an edit is made on those text boxes?

Comment: Yes thats what i want you can see my answer detailed

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is what i want ... I have used this code but it soesn't work :

```
 private void idE_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = sql.ds.Tables["Etablissement"].Clone();
            DataRow drow = sql.ds.Tables["Etablissement"].NewRow();
            sql.s = "Select * from Etablissement where Id_Etablissement = @Id_Etablissement";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql.s, sql.cn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Etablissement", idE.SelectedItem.ToString());
            sql.dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (sql.dr.Read())
            {
                drow[0] = sql.dr[0];
                drow[1] = sql.dr[1];
                drow[2] = sql.dr[2];
            }
            dt.ImportRow(drow);
            dgv.DataSource = dt;
            sql.dr.Close();
        }
            while (sql.dr.Read())
            {
                drow[0] = sql.dr[0];
                drow[1] = sql.dr[1];
                drow[2] = sql.dr[2];
            }
            dt.ImportRow(drow);
            dgv.DataSource = dt;
            sql.dr.Close();
        }
```